# Requests Python: Query the data and change using using payload requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I want to change the ‘is_app_enabled’ to true into the particular filterd market,
Statement: query the particular market, then change the value of is_app_enabled to true,
The web network request which i got is as below:

```
General: 
Request URL: http://10.76.98.167:5000/api/v1/apps/settings/dcp/
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.76.98.167:5000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://10.76.98.167:5000
Cache-Control: no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json
csrf-token: 8303a69ba4cfe891e7595f15b76f9ecfed1e2c96f75349533dae12faf2460248
Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2019 09:53:36 GMT
Server: nginx/1.15.0
Set-Cookie: session=.eJyrVopPK0otzlCyKikqTdVRis9MUbKqVlJIUrJSisryrPR18azyzQ018XcPNIzMSjbyzcrI9HVJN_J3yTbxcwk19A_xNPY1CrVVqgXqLUgtyk3MS80rgZlWWpxaBDZRKTEvMaeyJDO5WKkWAFXsJa0.D4NxIA.3hVVx9L-fUj7hAePOz4-aXWY3eQ; Expires=Mon, 01-Apr-2019 10:23:36 GMT; HttpOnly; Path=/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

Requests Headers:

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 72
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: session=.eJyrVopPK0otzlCyKikqTdVRis9MUbKqVlJIUrJSisryrPR18azyzQ018XcPNIzMSjbyzcrI9HVJN_J3yTbxcwk19A_xNPY1CrVVqgXqLUgtyk3MS80rgZlWWpxaBDZRKTEvMaeyJDO5WKkWAFXsJa0.D4Nw3A.9lXgT0AhT5QFmmK6HJK9_G7aTTg
csrf-token: 8303a69ba4cfe891e7595f15b76f9ecfed1e2c96f75349533dae12faf2460248
Host: 10.76.98.167:5000
Origin: http://10.76.98.167:5000
Referer: http://10.76.98.167:5000/explorer/v2/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36

Request Payload :

{query: "market == 'Austin'", is_app_enabled: true, tz: "Asia/Kolkata"}
is_app_enabled: true
query: "market == 'Austin'"
tz: "Asia/Kolkata"
```

I Have tried with the below code:

```
import requests
import json

s=requests.session()
report_url= 'http://10.76.98.167:5000/api/v1/apps/settings/dpo/'

payload = {query: "market == 'DEL'", is_app_enabled: true, tz: "Asia/Kolkata"}
r = s.post(report_url,data=paylaod)

print("second",report_url)
```

it's throwing an error : payload = ‘{query: "market == 'DEL'", is_app_enabled: true, tz: "Asia/Kolkata"}
NameError: name 'query' is not defined,

How to query the data and update the particular field?

Answer (score 0):

it's because without the quotes, it's looking at that as a variable, which is not defined. try:

```
payload = {"query": "market == 'DEL'", 
           "is_app_enabled": "true", 
           "tz": "Asia/Kolkata"}
```

Also, check your spelling of `payload` here:

```
r = s.post(report_url,data=paylaod)
```